# Ubuntu 20.04 unattended upgrade vs. dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, lubuntu, unattended-upgrades

Believe me, I did google but didn't find the positive answer.

My question ist:
Can
**unattended-upgrades**
perform the same as
**apt-get dist-upgrade**
if configured correctly? If yes, what should be the config?

Since I am not a Linux expert it's hard for me to know, whether my config is already enabling dist-upgrade or not.

I have unattended-upgrades installed on my Lubuntu 20.04.

In /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades I have

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-b
```

Thanks for shedding some light to my darkness.

Comment: Yes, and it looks like it is configured the way you wanted.

Comment: you won't be offered an upgrade to the latest LTS (22.04) for a while yet so no worries.

Comment: Very confusingly, both "unattended-upgrades" and "dist-upgrade" have nothing to do with an upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04. Whoever named those thinngs, apparently, had zero imagination.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Thanks for your quick assessment! I'm relieved :-)

Comment: @mikewhatever: One more question though: Which of the lines ensures the dist-upgrade (as opposed to simple upgrade)?

Comment: The "...-updates" line you've uncommented should make sure all updated are auto-installed. By default, only security updates are auto-installed.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever